# Find the distinct equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $B = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and let $\{0\},\{1,3,4\},\{2\}$ be a partition of $B$ that induces a relation $Q$. Find the distinct equivalence classes of $Q$.

Comment: Guess wildly: what do you imagine they would be?

Comment: Do you understand, Todd, what it means for a partition to induce a relation?

Comment: Honestly not really, I've been busy dealing with my wife having mobility issues due to an accident and taking care of my kids whilst working overnight so I'm a tad exhausted and having brain farts on what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: {0} x {0} = {(0,0)}  
{1,3,4} x {1,3,4} = {(1,1) ,(1,3) ,(1,4), (3,1), (3,3) (3,4) (4,1), (4,3) ,(4,4)}  
{2} x {2} = {(2,2)}  

Q= {(0,0), (1,1) ,(1,3) ,(1,4), (3,1), (3,3) (3,4) (4,1), (4,3) ,(4,4) ,(2,2)}

Comment: What you're supposed to do, when you have the time to concentrate on it, and after you've had some sleep, is go to whatever source you are learning this from, and understand what it means for a partition to induce a relation. Maybe you first have to understand what a partition is, and what a relation is, and what an equivalence class is. The question you ask is so close to the definitions of the concepts involved that learning those definitions is absolutely for sure what you're supposed to do. When you can.

Comment: At least BrianO is helping me walk through my other problem. You seem to have misread that my wife had an accident, might have a torn ACL so I've been busy. I got an extension on this problem until 11:59pm EST tonight so I'm trying to get this done. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did help you. I told you exactly what you need to do to understand and then solve the problem. You need to learn what a partition is. You need to learn what a relation is, and what an equivalence relation is, and what an equivalence class is. You need to learn what it means for a partition to induce a relation. I could write out all the definitions, but I'm sure you have them all in whatever materials you have been given to study (and, if not, I've given you the search terms to find them on the web). Continued next comment.

Comment: Please get started on this. When/if you get stuck, come back and ask for clarification. If you want to be sure that I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it, so I get notified.

Comment: I already included what I believe Q would equal after looking through this @Gerry

Comment: You're correct about what $Q$ is. Now figure out what the equivalence classes of $Q$ are. (When you do, you'll see that it wasn't really necessary to determine $Q$.)

Comment: I have feeling it would be {0}, {1,3,4] and {2} but that seems to easy. Especially if I have to find distinct equivalence classes. Doesn't that mean I have to go through reflexive transitive and symmetry or no because it already gives me the partition to work with? @BrianO

Comment: No. C'mon, that's impossible: the members of any equivalence class are members of the underlying set, which here is $B$, and $8\notin B$. There's no addition involved here. Forget about the other problem. The equivalence class of $x$ is all things "equivalent" to $x$, so in this case, it's all $y$ such that $xQy$. You know $Q$: you figured it out starting from the partition. It's really (really) easy to figure out the induced partition....

Comment: Your feeling is correct. It's easy, all right, but it's not tooo easy: I think the point of the exercise is to get you to realize this:  A partition $P$ of a set $A$ induces an equivalence relation $\sim_P$ on $A$, and an equivalence relation on $A$ induces a partition $R_P$. It turns out -- this is an excellent exercise -- that if $P$ is a partition then $P_{\sim_P} = P$, and if $R$ is an equivalence relation then  $R_{P_R} = R$. In other words, these two operations are inverses of each other.

Comment: Yeah, you get back the partition you started with. Similarly, if you had some explicit eq. rel. $R$, and the problem was: "Let $P$ be the partition induced by $R$; what is the equivalence relation induced by $P$?", then the answer would be.... $R$.

Comment: Review what you did to compute $Q$: you formed $p\times p$ for every $p\in$ the partition, then you took their union. All these products are disjoint. Two things $a,b\in B$ are $Q$-related $\iff$ they're in the same member of the partition. In fact, if you had to describe $Q$, you could say "$aQb \iff $a, b$ are in the same member of the partition".

Comment: Noo, maybe I read your longer reply hastily: {0}, {1,3,4}, and {2}. (I didn't, you had it right before.)

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. How do I give you a vote up?

Comment: Since these have all been comments rather than an answer, they count for less (1 point each). If you hover the mousepointer next to a (or over) comment, you'll see two icon appear: an up-arrowhead and a flag. If you hover over either, it turns red. Hover over the up-arrowhead and click it: that awards the comment +1 point. You might do that for any comment(s) that helped -- tips appreciated :)

Comment: I don't seem to have that option @BrianO

Comment: Tell ya what, I'll post an answer, and you can call that "correct" &/or upvote it.

Comment: perfect! @BrianO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computed the equivalence relation $Q$, which is good for practice, but as you'll see, there's absolutely no reason to compute it in order to solve this problem. 
Review what you did to compute $Q$: you formed $p\times p$ for every $p\in$ the partition, then you took their union. All these products are disjoint. Two things $a,b\in B$ are $Q$-related $\iff$ they're in the same member of the partition. In fact, if you had to describe $Q$, you could say "$aQb\iff a, b$ are in the same member of the partition". Thus, the equivalence classes of $Q$ (the partition induced by $Q$) are exactly the members of the partition: you're back to what you started from.

Rephrased: the equivalence classes of (i.e. the partition induced by) the equivalence relation $Q$ which is induced by the partition $P = \{\{0\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{2\}\}$ is just that partition you started with: $P$.

This exemplifies a couple of **general facts**:

- A partition $P$ of a set $A$ induces an equivalence relation $\sim_P$ on $A$, where $a \sim_P b \iff a,b \text{ are in the same member of the partition}$, and
- an equivalence relation on $A$ induces a partition $R_P$ (equal to the set of equivalence classes of $R$).

It turns out that if $P$ is a partition then $P_{\sim_P} = P$, and if $R$ is an equivalence relation then  $R_{P_R} = R$. In other words, these two operations are inverses of each other. [*Proof on request, but proving this is an excellent exercise.*]